# Cannot run automation script via Jenkins - getting kCGErrorFailure

Tags: macos, selenium, jenkins

I installed Jenkins locally and running on localhost. When I tried to run my scripts through Jenkins, I'm getting the following error:

[testng] Wed Oct 10 15:54:52 Automation.local java[60266] : kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.

I'm at a lost here so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your scripts are, but I assume it tries to draw to the screen? Perhaps open a window? Jenkins is likely running in a daemon context. A daemons context cannot directly talk to the window server in order to open windows. You'll need to be much more specific about what your scripts do in order to discuss how to address it in this case.

---

As noted, you're trying to open browser windows in a root daemon (i.e. LaunchDaemon) context. You can't do this. You need to run Jenkins as a normal program or as a LaunchAgent (i.e. after some user has logged in). See https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app for a useful wrapper. See [these setup docs](http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-set-up-jenkins-ci-on-mac.html) for discussion of setting it up as a agent rather than a daemon.

Comment: I'm using jenkins with ant to trigger my selenium scripts and the first step the script does is to open the browser window. Here's my open browser method:

Comment: public void setUrl() throws Exception {
 driver.get("http://google.com");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

Comment: Thanks, I created a Jenkins user and added a LaunchAgent using the new user.